# Is there a front + end web framework?

Tags: web-frameworks

I wish to know if there's a "full-stack" web framework. That is, one framework to handle both the front and back ends.

If not,
What combinations/recipes are popular nowadays?

Basically,
I need a web framework for a fast development of some site. It needs to support DB handling (thourgh ORM).

I'm pretty much versatile when it comes to languages though I'd rather not using PHP. I prefer JS/Java/python (not in a particular order)

Thanks!

Comment: Please, check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: http://www.gwtproject.org/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the "full-stack" Framework, but if the backend is responsible for rendering the html templates and CSS then maybe we can called that way, but I don't advise using that approach.

If you are developing a site, then I guess there are 3 or 4 famous languages (for the back-end) which are : python, php, rails and nodeJS, each one of them got one ot more frame works that you can use. For the front end if you are ready to learn, then you should use angular2 frame work (it uses typescript language), or you can simply use other known frame works.

For the time question : from a personal opinion, I tried php (laravel frame work) first and even most sites use it, I don't recommend it, it takes a bit of your time. Ruby (ROR for the frame work) is a bit difficult to learn and master so it's a far option if you don't have enough time, but I do recommend python with Django frame work, it's simple, easy to learn, and it doesn't take much of your time, and it support DB handling.

Hope that helps.